# SwiftUI/FireStore - How to display promoted content?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So I'm trying to implement a means of users promoting their content via in an in app purchase where once they pay the app will execute a function where a field on Firebase will be updated i.e. `isPromoted` to `true`.

The question is - How can I grab say the latest content all users have uploaded and at the same time get uploads where `isPromoted` is set to `true` and then display say one that is promoted say after every other 5 uploads? I hope I make sense.

Right now I'm thinking this:

```
func getLatestUserContent(){}

func getPromotedUserContent(){}

func mergeArrays() {
  var mergedArray = promotedArray + latestContentArray 
}
```

Or maybe

```
ForEach(latestArray, id: \.self) { latestPost in 
Image(latestPost)
if latestArray is divisible by latestPost which equals 5 (index /position in the array) {
ForEach(promotedArray, id: \.self) { promotedPost in 
Image(promotedPost)
      }
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about your current approach is not working?

Comment: @jnpdx I haven't approached it as of yet, rather just trying to figure out what approach would be the best way.

Comment: Probably best to give it a shot first and see what does or doesn't work and then approach your question from that perspective.

Comment: I will do! Appreciate the response mate! @jnpdx